# Why are we using linked list to address collisions in hash tables?

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

I was wondering why many languages (Java, C++, Python, Perl etc) implement hash tables using linked lists to avoid collisions instead of arrays?
I mean instead of buckets of linked lists, we should use arrays.
If the concern is about the size of the array then that means that we have too many collisions so we already have a problem with the hash function and not the way we address collisions. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: There appear to be 3 fields of applications for hashtables: 1. Those really giving memory in return for speed - they want to avoid collisions. 2. Those who rely on the overflow mechanism and want rather high fill grade of their tables, not minding collisions. 3. Games which usually call it transposition tables, who skip any overflow mechanism and assume that synonyms are not harmful over all.

Comment: in a number fo senses linked lists have advantages over arrays, for example they need not be consecutive in memory, they can make certain operations (like delete) faster and so on. But using arrays to implement hastable collisions is also fine

Comment: You can even use a BST to make sure you never get the worst case of `O(n)` if that's the issue - constants will be bad though. Bottom line, what ever suits your needs for your specific application is a fine choice as a bucket holder.

Comment: The potential overhead of having to reallocate an array should the bucket need to grow would probably outweight the benefit of having O(1) access to the bucket's elements.

Comment: @chepner:But if I need to grow the array often that means my hash function is the problem not the approach of the array. At least that is what I understand

Comment: @amit:Constants will be bad if I have many collisions. Which mean the hash function is bad. Right?

Comment: Are you totally sure that: *most of the languages implement hash tables using linked lists to avoid collisions*? Please provide a reference.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk:That was my impression so I corrected the OP. Do you have a reference of one that does not?

Comment: You're the one asserting they use linked lists; the burden of proving the statement is on you.

Comment: @Jim Yes, since Java 8, `java.util.HashMap` is using [balanced trees](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180).

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk:It replaces the linked list with a BST when over a threshold

Comment: Python doesn't use linked lists, or any buckets at all. It uses open addressing.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean instead of buckets of linked lists, we should use arrays.

Pros and cons to everything, depending on many factors.

The two biggest problem with arrays:

1. **changing capacity involves copying *all* content** to another memory area
2. you have to ***choose*** between:

   a) arrays of `Element*`s, adding one ***extra indirection*** during table operations, and one ***extra memory allocation per non-empty bucket*** with associated heap management overheads

   b) arrays of `Element`s, such that the pre-existing `Element`s ***iterators/pointers/references are invalidated*** by some operations on other nodes (e.g. `insert`) (the linked list approach - or 2a above for that matter - needn't invalidate these)

*...will ignore several smaller design choices about indirection with arrays...*

Practical ways to reduce copying from 1. include keeping excess *capacity* (i.e. currently unused memory for anticipated or already-erased elements), and - if `sizeof(Element)` is *much* greater than `sizeof(Element*)` - you're pushed towards arrays-of-`Element*s` (with "2a" problems) rather than `Element[]`s/2b.

---

There are a couple other answers claiming erasing in arrays is more expensive than for linked lists, but the opposite's *often* true: searching contiguous `Element`s is faster than scanning a linked list (less steps in code, more cache friendly), and once found you can copy the last array `Element` or `Element*` over the one being erased then decrement size.

---

> If the concern is about the size of the array then that means that we have too many collisions so we already have a problem with the hash function and not the way we address collisions. Am I misunderstanding something?

To answer that, let's look at what happens with a great hash function.  Packing a million elements into a million buckets using a cryptographic strength hash, a few runs of my program counting the number of buckets to which 0, 1, 2 etc. elements hashed yielded...

```
0=367790 1=367843 2=184192 3=61200 4=15370 5=3035 6=486 7=71 8=11 9=2
0=367664 1=367788 2=184377 3=61424 4=15231 5=2933 6=497 7=75 8=10 10=1
0=367717 1=368151 2=183837 3=61328 4=15300 5=3104 6=486 7=64 8=10 9=3
```

If we increase that to 100 million elements - still with load factor 1.0:

```
0=36787653 1=36788486 2=18394273 3=6130573 4=1532728 5=306937 6=51005 7=7264 8=968 9=101 10=11 11=1
```

We can see the ratios are pretty stable.  Even with load factor 1.0 (the default maximum for C++'s `unordered_set` and -`map`), 36.8% of buckets can be expected to be empty, another 36.8% handling one `Element`, 18.4% 2 Elements and so on.  For any given array resizing logic you can easily get a sense of how often it will need to resize (and potentially copy elements).  ***You're right that it doesn't look bad, and may be better than linked lists if you're doing lots of lookups or iterations, for this idealistic cryptographic-hash case.***

But, good quality hashing is relatively expensive in CPU time, such that general purpose hash-table supporting hash functions are often very weak: e.g. it's very common for C++ Standard library implementations of `std::hash<int>` to return their argument, and MS Visual C++'s `std::hash<std::string>` picks 10 characters evently spaced along the `string` to incorporate in the hash value, regardless of how long the `string` is.

Clearly implementation's experience has been that this combination of weak-but-fast hash functions and linked lists (or trees) to handle the greater collision proneness works out faster on average - and has less user-antagonising manifestations of obnoxiously bad performance - for everyday keys and requirements.

Comment: Is the copy of array content serious issue? I would expect that in a decent hash table we would only have a few numbers of collisions e.g. max of 8 elements in the array/8 nodes in the list

Comment: To prevent anybody else to perform same analysis for different load factor, I leave this link with explicit formula: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/31881/9350

Comment: @Jim: the cost of copying is likely not a serious issue if you're using a good hash function, but it *could* be a serious issue if you use a weak hash function (and many language implementation's provided hash functions are weak) and/or have keys provided by a hostile user that were calculated to collide.

Comment: @leventov: thank you very much - nice to see the maths behind it, and indeed that the numbers line up with my results for load factor 0.75 (which were `0=472183 1=354381 2=133140 3=32985 4=6299 5=892 6=111 7=9` on one run).

Comment: @TonyD, yes, and your 36.8% is just 1/e :)

Comment: `it's very common for C++ Standard library implementations of std::hash<int> to return their argument,` Java does the same. But isn't this a good approach?

Comment: @Jim: it's good *on average* for inputs that are fairly random themselves, but can be catestrophically collision prone for certain inputs: for example, say your inputs were all multiples of 8, and so was your table size, you could easily have all your keys hash to 1/8th of the table's buckets while the other buckets remain empty. That could easily happen if your keys were 8-byte aligned pointers that the hash function cast to numbers. If you care about a particular table's performance, it's best to sanity-check the hash function it's using.

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy 1**

Use (small) arrays which get instantiated and subsequently filled once collisions occur. 1 heap operation for the allocation of the array, then room for N-1 more. If no collision ever occurs again for that bucket, N-1 capacity for entries is wasted. List wins, if collisions are rare, no excess memory is allocated just for the probability of having more overflows on a bucket. Removing items is also more expensive. Either mark deleted spots in the array or move the stuff behind it to the front. And what if the array is full? Linked list of arrays or resize the array?

One potential benefit of using arrays would be to do a sorted insert and then binary search upon retrieval. The linked list approach cannot compete with that. But whether or not that pays off depends on the write/retrieve ratio. The less frequently writing occurs, the more could this pay off.

**Strategy 2**

Use lists. You pay for what you get. 1 collision = 1 heap operation. No eager assumption (and price to pay in terms of memory) that "more will come". Linear search within the collision lists. Cheaper delete. (Not counting `free()` here). One major motivation to think of arrays instead of lists would be to reduce the amount of heap operations. Amusingly the general assumption seems to be that they are cheap. But not many will actually know how much time an allocation requires compared to, say traversing the list looking for a match.

**Strategy 3**

Use neither array nor lists but store the overflow entries within the hash table at another location. Last time I mentioned that here, I got frowned upon a bit. Benefit: 0 memory allocations. Probably works best if you have indeed low fill grade of the table and only few collisions.

**Summary**

There are indeed many options and trade-offs to choose from. Generic hash table implementations such as those in standard libraries cannot make any assumption regarding write/read ratio, quality of hash key, use cases, etc. If, on the other hand all those traits of a hash table application are known (and if it is worth the effort), it is well possible to create an optimized implementation of a hash table which is tailored for the set of trade offs the application requires.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that the expected length of these lists is tiny, with only zero, one, or two entries in the vast majority of cases. Yet these lists may also become arbitrarily long in the worst case of a really bad hash function. And even though this worst case is not the case that hash tables are optimized for, they still need to be able to handle it gracefully.

Now, for an array based approach, you would need to set a minimal array size. And, if that initial array size is anything other then zero, you already have significant space overhead due to all the empty lists. A minimal array size of two would mean that you waste half your space. And you would need to implement logic to reallocate the arrays when they become full because you cannot put an upper limit to the list length, you need to be able to handle the worst case.

The list based approach is much more efficient under these constraints: It has only the allocation overhead for the node objects, most accesses have the same amount of indirection as the array based approach, and it's easier to write.

I'm not saying that it's impossible to write an array based implementation, but its significantly more complex and less efficient than the list based approach.

Comment: Linked lists are not smaller if one is clever with the arrays. Don't over-allocate for small array. A one-element array is then simply length + element, exactly as large as the linked list node (next pointer + element). A two element list is already more efficient. An empty array is equally small: If you always allocate the array externally, just store a null pointer in the hash table as you would for the linked list. If you want to inline the first node of the list, the equivalent for arrays is storing (length, first_element) if length = 1 and (length, pointer) otherwise. Again, same size.

Comment: For more than one element, you start actually *saving* space and get more cache hits. Anyway, my point is not that arrays are better for buckets (I'm not sure of that) but that linked lists don't have nearly as many advantages as you claim. The code isn't much more complex either, though the design is arguable a bit more complex.

Comment: @delnan Yes, if you are very careful, you can control the overhead of the arrays. Nevertheless, the way that arrays are usually applied (start with something like eight elements, double capacity on each reallocation) cannot be applied in this context. So this requires quite a bit of uncommon thought. To the complexity of the code: The linked list does not need to take a capacity into account or handle reallocation, it does not need to move entries, neither for insertion, nor for removal. The insertion is really a two-liner with linked lists. You don't get near that with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> **why** many languages (Java, C++, Python, Perl etc) implement hash tables using linked lists to avoid collisions instead of arrays?

I'm almost sure, at least for *most* from that "many" languages:

*Original implementors of hash tables for these languages just followed classic algorithm description from Knuth/other algorithmic book, and didn't even consider such subtle implementation choices.*

Some observations:

- Even using collision resolution with [separate chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) instead of, say, [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing), for "most generic hash table implementation" is seriously doubtful choice. My personal conviction -- it is not the right choice.
- When hash table's load factor is pretty low (that should chosen in nearly 99% hash table usages), the difference between the suggested approaches hardly could affect overall data structure perfromance (as *cmaster* explained in the beginning of his answer, and *delnan* meaningfully refined in the comments). Since generic hash table implementations in languages are not designed for high density, "linked lists vs arrays" is not a pressing issue for them.
- Returning to the topic question itself, I don't see any conceptual reason why linked lists should be better than arrays. I can easily imagine, that, in fact, arrays are faster on modern hardware / consume less memory with modern momory allocators inside modern language runtimes / operating systems. Especially when the hash table's key is primitive, or a copied structure. You can find some arguments backing this opinion here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_other_structures

  But the only way to find the correct answer (for particular CPU, OS, memory allocator, virtual machine and it's garbage collection algorithm, and the hash table use case / workload!) is to implement both approaches and compare them.

> Am I misunderstanding something?

No, you don't misunderstand anything, your question is legal. It's an example of fair confusion, when something is done in some specific way not for a strong reason, but, largely, by occasion.

Comment: Interesting answer +1. But how do you back up your statement that open addressing is usually the right choice. All textbooks mention it as "problematic" due to clustering effect

Comment: @Jim Clustering effect becomes considerable on high densities (that really needed really rarely, again by my conviction, as I said in the next paragraph). On low densities average chain length is about 1.1-1.3 items, (i. e. most "chains" are just sole entries), clustering, huh? You can say "what if somebody want to DOS us?" Real, but RARE case. But in Java now the most generic hash map impelementation thinks about this rare case.

Comment: @Jim well, I understand why they did this in Java 8, because some old web server software just use the generic map for caching publically accepted data, nobody will rewrite this software, however switching from linked lists to rb-trees when chain becomes > 8 doesn't affect normal Map performance, at all.

Comment: @Jim btw switching from *chains as arrays* (discussed in this question) to rb-trees would also be possible, any way the linked entries are not reused on this switch, because rb entries have different class.

Comment: I like open addressing - can be ~10x faster for small objects when you're doing insertions and lookups and no erase operations. Supporting erases requires differentiating never-used from in-use from was-in-use buckets, and if your table's subject to rapid insertions and erases without resizing much, the ratio of never-used to was-in-use buckets gets lower and lower, meaning you're spending time iterating over was-in-use buckets when doing lookups, insertions, erases etc.. A full rehash is often the only practical way to get back to top performance, which isn't great for real-time apps.

Comment: @Jim this concept is called *tombstone* slots (buckets). Linear hashing is usally implemented without tombstones, using so-called shift-deletion operation. In this case hash table's load factor and clustering isn't deteriorating in time, even on heavy removes and insertions, if the target load factor is chosen to be reasonably low.

Comment: @leventov:1) low/high densities I assume you mean number of entries in the table. Textbook state that open addressing deteriorates when table >50% full. That means that I would need to double the table each time it is half full. I think that in real world most hash map are > 70%full 2) What concept is called tombstone slots?I lost you there. I am sorry

Comment: Was-in-use buckets are called tombstones

Answer (score 1):

If is implemented using arrays, in case of insertion it will be costly due to reallocation which in case of linked list doesn`t happen.

Coming to the case of deletion we have to search the complete array then either mark it as delete or move the remaining elements. (in the former case it makes the insertion even more difficult as we have to search for empty slots).

To improve the worst case time complexity from o(n) to o(logn), once the number of items in a hash bucket grows beyond a certain threshold, that bucket will switch from using a linked list of entries to a balanced tree (in java).